# Can $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos(\theta)}\sin(\sin(\theta))\sin(nx)dx=\frac{\pi}{n!}$ be extened to non-integers?

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, gamma-function

It is well known that the fourier series for $e^{\cos(\theta)}\sin(\sin(\theta))$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n\theta)}{n!}$ which implies that

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos(\theta)}\sin(\sin(\theta))\sin(n\theta)dx=\frac{\pi}{n!}$$ for $n>0$. My question is if this identity can be extended to fractional values such as $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos(\theta)}\sin(\sin(\theta))\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})d\theta=2\sqrt{\pi} $$

Comment: No! Try expanding with the half-angle formulas

Comment: Numerical evidence suggests that
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos\theta} \sin(\sin\theta)\sin(n\theta)\,d\theta \simeq \frac\pi{n!} - \frac34\frac{\sin((n-1)\pi)}{n^2+1},
$$
where of course $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$

Comment: Sorry, it should be $+\tfrac34\dots$, not $-$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Incomplete answer: only numerical experiments.**

Let me define
$$
s(n) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{\cos\theta}\sin(\sin\theta)\sin(n\theta)\,d\theta
$$
and
$$
g(n) = \frac{s(n)-\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(n+1)}}{\sin\bigl((n-1)\pi\bigr)}.
$$
Numerical evidence suggests that $g(n)\to0$; but how fast? Let's try to extract some more information.

Here I plot $-\log\bigl(g(n)\bigr)$ for $n\in[1,20]$:
[image]

It looks like a logarithm, so it seems natural to try to fit it with
$$
-\log\bigl(g(n)\bigr) = a+b\log(n+c).
$$

By fiddling a bit (and looking at larger ranges of $n$) one can see that $b$ has to be $2$, so we have $a+2\log(n+c)$. The value $g(1)$ seems to be around $0.5$, a bit less, so we impose $a+2\log(1+b)=\log(2)$. Moreover, by looking at large values, we deduce that $a=1-\log(2)$ seems a good value. Therefore our approximation is
$$
g(n) \simeq \frac{2}{\bigl(2+\sqrt e(n-1)\bigr)^2},
$$
which leads to
$$
s(n) \simeq \frac{\pi}{\Gamma(n+1)} + \frac{2\sin\bigl((n-1)\pi\bigr)}{\bigl(2+\sqrt e(n-1)\bigr)^2} .
$$

Comment: I see, so at integer value it is equal to $\frac{\pi}{n!}$ but otherwise it is not.

Comment: Yes. Even just at $n=1/2$, we get $s(1/2)=\tfrac2e + \sqrt\pi \mathrm{erf}(1)$ instead of $2\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: I'm still intrigued to find a closed expression for $s(n)$