# Fun integral -help

Tags: calculus, integration, recreational-mathematics

A friend of mine found this interesting problem in one of Feynman's books one day and neither of us ever managed to come up with a solution.
The question is to show that the following two integrals are equivalent and equal to $ \frac{\left(\pi\ p^{a}\right)}{2\left(a!\right)}$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi\ }e^{p\cos x\ }\sin\left(p\sin\left(x\right)\right)\sin\left(ax\right)dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi\ }e^{p\cos x\ }\cos\left(p\sin\left(x\right)\right)\cos\left(ax\right)dx$$

The fact that the answer contains a factorial suggests to us we might need the Gamma Function but we are not very familiar with how to apply it here. Anyone has a step-by-step solution to this?

Comment: One approach: think of e.g. the first integral as (related to) Fourier transforms of $e^{p \cos(x)} \sin(p \sin(x))$. See e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927115), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018807), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099879). Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472345), wherein Feynman's trick is used---maybe that's how he would've wanted it done.